# Drag and Drop only PDF files

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, listbox

I have the following code that list the files that i drag  in a listbox. 
now i need to filter so it can only list PDF files and discard the rest.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBoxFiles.AllowDrop = true;
    listBoxFiles.DragDrop += listBoxFiles_DragDrop;
    listBoxFiles.DragEnter += listBoxFiles_DragEnter;
}

private void listBoxFiles_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}

private void listBoxFiles_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
    foreach (string file in files)
        listBoxFiles.Items.Add(file);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    private void listBoxFiles_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            if (Path.GetExtension(file) == "pdf")
            {
                listBoxFiles.Items.Add(file);
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, if it works - you can make it in one line with Linq

Comment: That didn't work, It seem like there is something with the if statement. it always gets a false.
EDIT: I changed the condition to .pdf and it worked. Thanks